# detect particular app push notification in notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

If there is notification in notification center, clear that app 
NSUserdefault, without clicking on notification.

```
UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];      
NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
NSString *msg =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userInfoCurrent];
```

Tried this, but not working

Answer (score 1):

If the App is in foreground or was brought to foreground due to user tapping on the notification, you can detect the notification in 
*application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:* method.

If the App has been launch due to user tapping on the notification, you can detect the notification in the *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* method.

If the App was not in foreground, there is no way to detect a notification unless the user taps on the notification.